# Javascript List clarification

Tags: javascript, list, null

```
var list = {};
list[19] = 'kapooya';
list[20] = 'apples';
delete list[19];
```

Does 
    list[19] == 'apples' or null?

Comment: neither, this is syntax error.

Comment: it would be {'kapooya'} in stead of 'kapooya', right?

Comment: @ArjunPatel refer to the comment above your comment.

Comment: I'm running a node server and use session ID's as the index and I do not get any errors. Anyone know why?

Comment: Did you try it? What did you get?

Comment: I created list as this.list = {}. I got this.list[20] to be apples. and this.list[19] to be null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the syntax error you get when using `var`before `list[19] = 'kapooya'`, `list[19]` is `undefined` after the `delete`, not `null`.

Technically you are not creating a list but an object, or a map, or a hash, or a dictionary, however you wish to refer to it.

The correct syntax for working with lists, or in the case of javascript, Arrays, is `var list= [];` be aware that the `delete` operator doesn't work on array items.

Answer (score 4):

```
var list = {};
list[19] = 'kapooya';
list[20] = 'apples';
delete list[19];
```

( var list[xx] would not work due to syntax error )

list[19] would be undefined.

Comment: Also note that "list" isn't a super-good name for a variable that's not much like a list.  The initialization could be changed from `{}` to `[]` to make it make more sense.